# C# Linq query search for a single keyword in multiple text files

Tags: c#, linq, filesystems

You have a directory `C:\jimmybuffett\`

Inside this directory are two text files:
`songlist1.txt`

Here is the text inside `songlist1.txt`:

> Margaritaville
>
> Boat Drinks
>
> Fins

The second file is:
`songlist2.txt`

Here is the text inside `songlist2.txt`:

> Margaritaville
>
> Boat Drinks Fins

I trying to write a Linq query that search through all files in the folder `jimmybuffett` and finds files that contain the song title "Fins".

Here is what I have:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String strPath = @"C:\jimmybuffett";
        String strSong = "Fins";

        var songs = from song in Directory.GetFiles(strPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                    where File.ReadAllLines(song).Contains(strSong)
                    select song;

        foreach(var song in songs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(song);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press <enter> to continue");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

This Linq query finds `songlist1.txt` because the search term "Fins" in on a separate line.

However `songlist2.txt` is not found because the search term "Fins" is on the same line as "Boat Drinks".

My question is how can I modify my Linq query so that I'm able to identify files that have the search term anywhere in the line.

This would be a like `%Fins%` SQL query.

I'm aware that I could use a Regular Expression but I'm wondering if I can do this right from my Linq query.

Thanks

Comment: @stuartd you should write that as an answer so that he can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `Any` 
like this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {


        String strPath = @"C:\jimmybuffett";
        String strSong = "Fins";

        var songs = from song in Directory.GetFiles(strPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                    where File.ReadAllLines(song).Any(x=>x.Contains(strSong))
                    select song;

        foreach(var song in songs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(song);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press <enter> to continue");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```